# Need assistance with formula syntax

Tags: formula, picklist

Trying to utilize a picklist value to modify a territory assignment identified by state.

My original formula, very simple:

```
IF(LEN( {!State})=0, "None",
IF(CONTAINS("AK:AZ:CA:HI:NV:NM:OR:UT:WA", {!State}), "West",
IF(CONTAINS("CO:ID:MT:KS:OK:TX:WY", {!State}), "Central",
IF(CONTAINS("CT:ME:MA:NH:NY:PA:RI:VT", {!State}), "East",
IF(CONTAINS("AL:AR:DC:DE:FL:GA:KY:LA:MD:MS:NC:NJ:SC:TN:VA:WV", {!State}), "South",
IF(CONTAINS("IL:IN:IA:MI:MN:MO:NE:ND:OH:SD:WI", {!State}), "North", "Other"))))))
```

Now I need to put in a modifier by way of a picklist field that says if the `Industry value = Retail` then it will utilize a different model for territory assignment, example:

```
IF(CONTAINS("AK:AZ:CA:HI:NV:NM:OR:UT:WA", {!State}), "West",
IF(CONTAINS("IL:IN:IA:MI:MN:MO:NE:ND:OH:SD:WI:CO:ID:MT:KS:OK:TX:WY:AL:AR:DC:LA:MD:MS", {!State}), "Central",
IF(CONTAINS("CT:ME:MA:NH:NY:PA:RI:VT:DE:FL:GA:KY:NC:NJ:SC:TN:VA:WV", {!State}), "East", "Other")))
```

I am having trouble adding the picklist modifier due to errors return results. Can Someone offer some assistance?

**EDIT :** here's the different versions I tried and the errors

**Version 1**

```
AND( ISPICKVAL(Industry,"Retail"),         
CONTAINS(CASE("IL:IN:IA:MI:MN:MO:NE:ND:OH:SD:WI:CO:ID:MT:KS:OK:TX:WY:AL:AR:DC:LA:MD:MS", State), 
"Central", "None"))
```

> Error: Incorrect number of parameters for function 'CASE()'. Expected
>   2, received

**Version 2**

```
 AND( ISPICKVAL(Industry,"Retail"),
 CONTAINS ( TEXT("IL:IN:IA:MI:MN:MO:NE:ND:OH:SD:WI:CO:ID:MT:KS:OK:TX:WY:AL:AR:DC:LA:MD:
 MS", State), "Central", "None"))
```

> Error: Incorrect number of parameters for function 'TEXT()'. Expected
>   1, received 2

Comment: What is the error message that you're getting? What have you tried so far?

Comment: AND(
ISPICKVAL(Industry,"Retail"),CONTAINS (CASE("IL:IN:IA:MI:MN:MO:NE:ND:OH:SD:WI:CO:ID:MT:KS:OK:TX:WY:AL:AR:DC:LA:MD:MS", State), "Central", "None"))


Error: Incorrect number of parameters for function 'CASE()'. Expected 2, received 2



AND(
ISPICKVAL(Industry,"Retail"),CONTAINS (TEXT("IL:IN:IA:MI:MN:MO:NE:ND:OH:SD:WI:CO:ID:MT:KS:OK:TX:WY:AL:AR:DC:LA:MD:MS", State), "Central", "None"))



Error: Incorrect number of parameters for function 'TEXT()'. Expected 1, received 2

Comment: AND(
ISPICKVAL(Industry = Retail),CONTAINS (TEXT("IL:IN:IA:MI:MN:MO:NE:ND:OH:SD:WI:CO:ID:MT:KS:OK:TX:WY:AL:AR:DC:LA:MD:MS", State), "Central", "None"))

Error: Field Industry is a picklist field. Picklist fields are only supported in certain functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
IF(ISPICKVAL(Industry, "Retail") && CONTAINS("IL:IN:IA:MI:MN:MO:NE:ND:OH:SD:WI:CO:ID:MT:KS:OK:TX:WY:AL:AR:DC:LA:MD:MS", ShippingState), "Central", "None")
```

There is no `State` field on the Account, it's either BillingState or ShippingState.

Comment: You are correct as far as the fields, this is for the Lead object, I will migrate to the Account and Contact object at a later date. Let me check this out and see if it returns the desired results.

Comment: I assumed it's Account :) Also there is no need to wrap the field name into an expression `{!}` when used within a function

Comment: Bachovski, worked brilliantly, I just had to remember that every formula function in SFDC is linear so that item had to be at the top of the list. Thank you very much for the insight. I will update the formula to rid it of the { ! } as well. How do I give you credit for the advice?

Comment: I'm glad it helped and you resolved the problem. You can easily extend it to cater for the rest of your cases now. You can upvote and accept this answer in order to give credit and close the question ;)

Comment: I do have one final question, what do the ampersands designate as operators in the logic string?

Comment: They stand for logical `AND`. Instead of using `AND(X, Y)` you can use  `X && Y`. Same thing goes for `OR`, where you can use `||`